# Can JSF 2.0 be used with Websphere application server version 7.x

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2, websphere, websphere-7

Can JSF 2.0 be used with WebSphere Application Server version 7.x?

If so, how?

Answer (score 13):

The [WebSphere Infocenter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12019464/pretty-faces-config-issues-on-websphere-application-server-jsf2/12073347#12073347) indicates that the right way to change to an alternative JSF implementation is to create a WebSphere Shared Library with the isolated classloader option enabled.

Any modules that need JSF 2 would be associated with the new shared library, and then the application would start with JSF 2 instead of JSF 1.2.

It is also [necessary to have fix pack 7.0.0.19 or later installed](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PM40949).

Comment: You talk about information provided on the IBM Infocenter site, but you don't provide a link. Why?

Comment: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tweb_jsf.html

Comment: Maybe I'm doing something wrong, but this did not work for me.  When I do follow those instructions, it's still trying to load the SUN JSF-1.2 reference implementation.

Comment: OK, I got it.  I needed to run some fixpacks for WAS and make sure that the JSF version was at least 2.0.4.  Now it's working.  +1

Comment: @Ian McLaird, can you share what you did step by step, I'm having a hard time I get HttpSession not found after creating a shared library? what jars do you put on your shared library?

Comment: @Joset, It's now been so long that I don't remember all the steps, but the two jars that I used were jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar, with the versions that I listed in my previous comment.  I needed WAS 7.0.0.19 and JSF 2.0.4 or later.

Answer (score 0):

Websphere ships with JSF 1.2.something and it loads that by default. To use a different JSF library (or any other library that WS provides such as commons-logging) you need to change the way the classloader prioritizes locations. They call it 'parent last" meaning load your libs then the WS versions.

Comment: Yes but parent last is not an option when you have multiple apps some using older version

Answer (score 0):

I've been struggling to solve this for days. Here's how I solved it.

Use the following library: **javax.faces-2.1.7.jar**

If you are on PrimeFaces 3.1: **primefaces-3.1.1.jar**

Application Server instance: **Class Loading - Parent Last**

Enterprise Application instance (war Module): **Class Loading - Parent Last**

Make sure to remove all Servlet Container libraries such as those needed by Tomcat.

Comment: Have you used the GlassFish implementation? The search by name of jar suggests that. Was it with WebSphere 7.0?

Answer (score 0):

Step by step setting MyFaces 2.0 on WebSphere Application Server v7 as shared library as IBM recommends:
http://wasbehindtheglass.blogspot.co.uk/

I have applied similar steps for Majorra/JSF 2.0.4 and created a shared library using only jsf-api.jar and jsf-impl.jar. As @Ian McLaird has told WAS 7.0.0.19 and JSF 2.0.4 are required. JSF 2.1.x requires Servlet 3 and is not supported by WAS7

Comment: And if your are using RAD and you don't want to change set the shared library from WAS7 admin console each time you deploy the application, then you can include a deployment descriptor (named as deployment.xml) in your project which sets the shared library. See the link for details: http://www.webspheretools.com/sites/webspheretools.nsf/docs/How%20to%20set%20the%20class%20loading%20policy%20to%20parent%20last%20using%20configuration%20files%20shipped%20within%20the%20EAR

Comment: Have you tried with MyFaces 2.1 or you're writing that it won't work basing on other source? If so, could you post it?

Answer (score 0):

My Experience:

-> WAS 7.0.0.11 on Windows

-> javax.faces-2.0.11.jar in WEB-INF/lib of my War application

-> WAS Shared librairies with javax.faces-2.0.11.jar with Isolated Class Loader

-> WAS Shared librairies associated with my War App

-> No change on Class Loader for instance and application (PARENT_FIRST)

With this conf (above) the application works fine with JSF 2.0 on WAS 7.
if i delete the javax.faces-2.0.11.jar from my War app, it doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked for me

- Create a shared library and put your JSF 2.0 jars in it.
- Also add EL 2.2 API and EL-Impl 2.2 jars as well since JSF 2.0 implicitly needs this.
- Add this library to your application and make classloader preference as PARENT_LAST.

Change web.xml as following

```
 <context-param>
                <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
                <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

Thats it .

Answer (score 0):

Hi I could run my website using this libraries

[image: librerias]

Configuring in web.xml of my project

```
 <context-param>
    <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
    <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Configuring in websphere to load my libraries (Parent Last)

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys!

It worked with a newer version of javax.faces. See the maven dependencies:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.glassfish</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.faces</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.29-08</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Don't forget to add the following in your web.xml:

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>com.sun.faces.expressionFactory</param-name>
   <param-value>com.sun.el.ExpressionFactoryImpl</param-value>
</context-param>
```

And finally change the WebSphere class loader order of the application and the module to the **(parent last)** settings:
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/urun_rclassloader_inst.html

Regards