# JSF 2 and Websphere 7.0 don't want to run

Tags: jsf-2, websphere-7

I am having some trouble with JSF2 and websphere 7.0. I have searched in the internet but nothing. The thing looks to be that websphere puts its 1.2 libraries and override my 2.0 libs. The app is working fine in apache-tomcat

Thirst of all, when i try to get an xhtml page (with simple html the app works, the problem is with jsf) the server shows the error:

could not find factory: javax.faces.context.FacesContextFactory

i've read that i had to use the "parent last" option in the class loader section, but it didn't worked. Then i went to jsp and jsf options on the web module properties, and there i can choose between Sun reference implementation 1.2 and MyFaces 1.2, the sun was selected, so i choose myfaces and now the error is another one: if i try to go to "something.xhtml", it redirects to "something.jsf", which doesn't exists..

any idea?

thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718934/can-jsf-2-0-be-used-with-websphere-application-server-version-7-x Check answer of RDean (currently the highest voted one).

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you didn't include the JSF implementation on your classpath.

Here's how I solved it.

Use the following library: **javax.faces-2.1.7.jar**

If you are on PrimeFaces 3.1: **primefaces-3.1.1.jar**

Application Server instance: **Class Loading - Parent Last**

Enterprise Application instance (war Module): **Class Loading - Parent Last**

Make sure to remove all Servlet Container libraries such as those needed by Tomcat.