# Classloader issue in WebSphere Application server 7.x

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, websphere, xstream, websphere-7

> com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLOutputFactoryImpl incompatible with
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory
>
> com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLOutputFactoryImpl incompatible with
>   javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory

Removed "jsr173_1.0_api.jar", "stax-api-1.0-2.jar" that has "XMLOutputFactory" and "XMLInputFactory" classes from APP(Web-inf/lib) to avoid any collision with server versions.

Also changed the war class loader order to "parent last" and
policy to "Single class loader for application" in WebSphere admin
console. Have made this change to give priority to application jars `WebInf/lib` than server jars.

Below is the stack-trace.

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLOutputFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory
                                 javax.faces.FacesException: #{tBean.persist}: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLOutputFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.component.UICommand.broadcast(UICommand.java:315)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.broadcastEvents(UIViewRoot.java:794)
    at javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processApplication(UIViewRoot.java:1259)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.InvokeApplicationPhase.execute(InvokeApplicationPhase.java:81)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1655)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1595)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:131)
    at org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.testtech.myapp.admin.authentication.UrlAuthorization.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.testtech.myapp.admin.authentication.UrlAuthentication.doFilter(Unknown Source)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ocpsoft.pretty.PrettyFilter.doFilter(PrettyFilter.java:114)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.FilterInstanceWrapper.doFilter(FilterInstanceWrapper.java:188)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:116)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:77)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterManager.doFilter(WebAppFilterManager.java:895)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:932)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.handleRequest(ServletWrapper.java:500)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapperImpl.handleRequest(ServletWrapperImpl.java:178)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.CacheServletWrapper.handleRequest(CacheServletWrapper.java:91)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WebContainer.handleRequest(WebContainer.java:864)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.handleRequest(WSWebContainer.java:1583)
    at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.channel.WCChannelLink.ready(WCChannelLink.java:183)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleDiscrimination(HttpInboundLink.java:455)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpInboundLink.handleNewInformation(HttpInboundLink.java:384)
    at com.ibm.ws.http.channel.inbound.impl.HttpICLReadCallback.complete(HttpICLReadCallback.java:83)
    at com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
    at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
    at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)
    at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1550)
Caused by: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLOutputFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:102)
    at com.sun.faces.application.ActionListenerImpl.processAction(ActionListenerImpl.java:102)
    ... 42 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.ibm.xml.xlxp2.api.stax.XMLOutputFactoryImpl incompatible with javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory
    at javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory.newInstance(XMLOutputFactory.java:98)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxDriver.getOutputFactory(StaxDriver.java:157)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.io.xml.StaxDriver.createWriter(StaxDriver.java:109)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:802)
    at com.thoughtworks.xstream.XStream.toXML(XStream.java:792)
    at com.testtech.UI.z.service.zService.createz(Unknown Source)
    at com.testtech.UI.z.web.zBean.persist(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:600)
    at com.sun.el.parser.AstValue.invoke(AstValue.java:234)
    at com.sun.el.MethodExpressionImpl.invoke(MethodExpressionImpl.java:297)
    at com.sun.faces.facelets.el.TagMethodExpression.invoke(TagMethodExpression.java:105)
    at javax.faces.component.MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.invoke(MethodBindingMethodExpressionAdapter.java:88)
    ... 43 more
```

JSF2.1.2
Spring 3.1.0
Prettyfaces-jsf2-3.3.2
Primefaces 3.2 
WebSphere Application Server 7.0.0.9

> [ibm page](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v6r0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.websphere.express.doc%2Finfo%2Fexp%2Fae%2Fttrb_classload_viewer.html) 
>   When troubleshooting class loading problems, you might need to
>   override classes visible to a parent class loader. To override such
>   classes with those specific to an application, set the Class loader
>   mode to Parent last on the class loader that contains the application
>   classes on its classpath. An application can override classes visible
>   to a parent class loader, but doing so can result in a
>   ClassCastException or UnsatisfiedLinkError if there is a mixed use of
>   overridden classes and non-overridden classes.

Comment: This doesn't look like a JSF problem, still leave the tag because it could be related with JSF projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using a third party JSF implementation. As a first step I'd suggest you to check if you have configured it right. Here is the infocenter link for [Configuring JavaServer Faces implementation](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wasinfo/v7r0/topic/com.ibm.websphere.nd.multiplatform.doc/info/ae/ae/tweb_jsf.html).

Basically you must

- create an isolated shared library
- put your JSF libraries and its dependencies in it
- associate shared library with your module
- set application classloader policy to PARENTLAST

Comment: Creating Isolated shared library(Environment -> Shared Libraries -> Class path and native path) for xstream jars and associate with application solved the class loading issue. Thank you