# What is the newest version of MyFaces that can be used with IBM WebSphere 7.0

Tags: jsf-2, websphere, myfaces

I'm using IBM WebSphere 7.0 with MyFaces 2.0.7 installed as shared library.

Because there are issues with PrimeFaces (for example, p:messages autoUpdate not working) I'm considering the upgrade to newer version (which is not trivial, because this must be the team decision in corporation).

So, my question is, which is the newest version of MyFaces that will work with IBM WebSphere 7.0? The newest version is for now 2.1.10, but according to the answer to the question [Can JSF 2.0 be used with Websphere application server version 7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718934/can-jsf-2-0-be-used-with-websphere-application-server-version-7-x/10249636#10249636) MyFaces versions starting from 2.1 will not work with WebSphere 7.0.

Have someone managed to run version 2.1.x? If so, which version, and was something additional to do? As I said, I've successfully configured shared library, similar to solution from article like that: http://wasbehindtheglass.blogspot.co.uk/2011/11/myfaces-20-and-websphere-application.html

Answer (score 1):

The **MyFaces Core 2.1.10** works well with IBM WebSphere 7.0.

Release notes can be found at [MyFaces Core 2.1.10](https://issues.apache.org/jira/secure/ReleaseNote.jspa?projectId=10600&version=12323259).

Comment: So, you're simply packing it as shared library and it works without problems?

Comment: Yeah, it works. Let me know if you find any issues. Make sure that there are no dependencies.

Comment: Could you edit your answer and write the jars you're using in your shared library? Are you using WebSphere-MyFaces20-annotation-provider.jar?

Comment: Doesn't work for me. java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/myfaces/shared_impl/util/ClassUtils The myfaces-impl 2.0.7 contains that class, and the 2.1.10 not