# How to Remove JSF 1.2 from websphere 7.0?

Tags: jsf-1.2, websphere-7

Is there any we can remove the JSF 1.2 libs from the websphere 7? I tried searching JSF libs in the Websphere server installation directory but could not find them.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

JSF 1.2 is part of Java EE 5. WebSphere is Jave EE 5 compliant so I doubt that you can remove parts of the Jave EE logic.

You can use JSF 2 though. Just make sure you load your application libaries with JSF 2 first. Check https://stackoverflow.com/a/2211960/1022141 as well.