# MyFaces 2.1.16 and WebSphere 7

Tags: jsf-2, websphere-7, myfaces

I'm working with the following:
IBM WebSphere 7.0.0.33
Apache MyFaces 2.1.16
Java 1.6
Servlet Container 2.5
Just trying to get a simple Application going and getting errors.
I read here [JSF2.0 and WAS7](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SS7JFU_7.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.express.iseries.doc/info/iseriesexp/ae/tweb_jsf_annotation.html) about WAS7 configuration for MyFaces (It's for JSF2.0), but that did not help so far.
I'm trying to figure out now if WAS7 even supports JSF2.1 .
MyFaces says that Servelt Container of 2.5 is ok [MyFaces2.1](https://myfaces.apache.org/core21/), but on some other page here it was posted that JSF needs 3.0 (which is not available with WAS7).
So, which one is correct?
Should I be able to run JSF2.1 with WAS7 ? 
Thanks

Comment: What errors are you getting? Did you follow exactly the link you've attached?

Answer (score 0):

No, WAS 7 doesn't support JSF 2.1, not even WAS 8, not sure regarding WAS 8.5
However, you can define custom JSF implementation, look at this answer : [Can JSF 2.0 be used with Websphere application server version 7.x](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1718934/can-jsf-2-0-be-used-with-websphere-application-server-version-7-x)

Comment: Info about WAS v8 is not correct. WAS v8 fully supports [JSF 2.0](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/info/ae/ae/cweb_jsfmigrate.html?lang=en). By default it is MyFaces 2.0.

Comment: @Gas, you're absolutely right. I indented to write JSF 2.1, with JSF 2.0 and WAS 8.0 I'm working myself every day. It wasn't a good idea answer on somebody question late nigh.

Comment: WAS7 works fine with JSF2.1.x , as JSF2.1 min req is servlet 2.5, 2.2 however requires 2.2